# Split Equation in Double Column Page

Tags: equations

good afternoon everyone. I was wondering if anyone would know how I could get to split the equation I show in the image to fit the double column format.

I have tried multiline and split but having a parenthesis in the middle I can't get it to work and although there are several related answers I can't figure out what they do.

Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
 aksjdf añslkdfj asñldkf jasdlñfkj asdñlfkasj dfñlaskdjf asñldkfj asñdflkjasd ñflaksj dfñlaskdfj asñldkf jasñdlfkajs dñlfkasjd fñlaskdjf añlsdkfj asñldkfj asñldfka sdflkasjd fñlaskdj falsñdfkj asñldfkj asñldfk asñdlfk asjdñflka sdfñaskjdfñalskdjf añsldkf asñldkf 
 
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:calc_aceleracion}
    \vect{\ddot{q}_\mathrm{var}} = \vect{\Phi_{var}^{-1}}\left(\vect{q}\right) \cdot \left(- \vect{\Phi_z}\left(\vect{q}\right)\cdot \ddot{\vect{z}} - \\
    \vect{\dot{\Phi}_{var}}\left(\vect{q},\vect{\dot{q}}\right) \cdot \vect{\dot{q}_{var}} - \vect{\dot{\Phi}_z} \left(\vect{q},\vect{\dot{q}} \right)\cdot \vect{\dot{z}} \right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Since you are already loading `mathtools` use the `multline` (notice its `multline` *not* `multiline`, only one `i`) environment:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
 
\begin{multline}
\label{eq:calc_aceleracion}
    \vect{\ddot{q}_\mathrm{var}} = \vect{\Phi_{var}^{-1}}\left(\vect{q}\right) \cdot \left(- \vect{\Phi_z}\left(\vect{q}\right)\cdot \ddot{\vect{z}} - \vphantom{\dot{\Phi}} \right.\\
    \left.\vect{\dot{\Phi}_{var}}\left(\vect{q},\vect{\dot{q}}\right) \cdot \vect{\dot{q}_{var}} - \vect{\dot{\Phi}_z} \left(\vect{q},\vect{\dot{q}} \right)\cdot \vect{\dot{z}} \right)
\end{multline}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

I've added in an extra `\right.` and `\left.` to have all pairs match up in each line. I've also added `\vphantom{\dot{\Phi}}` as the tallest term in the second half of the equation so that the opening`(` is as large as the closing `)`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so so mucho for all your help. It's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually you could `split` your equation with the advice to use `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` because, being splitted your equation, you will have errors with `\left(` and `\right)`. After I have deleted the `\left(` and `\right)` on `(\vect{q})` (for example) to have the correct size of the rounded brackets, and you will have all, as subscripts, the correct `\mathrm{var}` because any have been written as `{var}`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\vect{\ddot{q}_{\mathrm{var}}} & = \vect{\Phi_{\mathrm{var}}^{-1}}(\vect{q}) \cdot\bigl(-\vect{\Phi_z}(\vect{q})\cdot \ddot{\vect{z}}-\\
& \vect{\dot{\Phi}_{\mathrm{var}}}(\vect{q},\vect{\dot{q}}) \cdot \vect{\dot{q}_{\mathrm{var}}} - \vect{\dot{\Phi}_z}(\vect{q},\vect{\dot{q}})\cdot \vect{\dot{z}}\bigr)
\end{split}
\label{eq:calc_aceleracion}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]